# DataGridview result of query 0

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

does anyone know why I throws out zero as a result in datagridview, while my entire query code is correct .. This is my code below ..

```
boAPI4.Login login = new boAPI4.Login();
string cS = login.GetConnectionString();
DataAccess dA = new DataAccess(cS);
int userID = dA.getLpeID(login.GetBoUserNr());
PRAESENZZEIT q = new PRAESENZZEIT();
q.ZPZ_LPE_ID = userID;
if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    db.Open();
string query = "SELECT per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS Stunden" +
               " FROM DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT zei INNER JOIN DB.dbo.A_PERSONAL per ON zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID = per.LPE_ID" +
                $" WHERE zei.ZPZ_Datum BETWEEN '{dtFromDate.Value}' AND '{dtToDate.Value}' AND zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID='{userID.ToString()}' GROUP BY per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum ORDER BY zei.ZPZ_Datum, per.LPE_Nr;";
pRAESENZZEITBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<PRAESENZZEIT>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);
```

and this is the same query that should be written in datagridview

```
  SELECT per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS Stunden FROM DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT zei INNER JOIN DB.dbo.A_PERSONAL per ON zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID = per.LPE_ID WHERE zei.ZPZ_Datum BETWEEN '16.12.2014 13:56:00' AND '18.12.2017 15:15:17'AND zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID='196' GROUP BY per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum ORDER BY zei.ZPZ_Datum, per.LPE_Nr;
```

[image: [This is my result in base and datagridview]]

definition of class PRAESENZZEIT

```
 public class PRAESENZZEIT
{
    public int LPE_Nr { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_Datum { get; set; }
    public double ZPZ_Std100 { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_LPE_ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime ZPZ_Von { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_Bis { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_Std { get; set; }

    public int ZPZ_ID { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_Jahr { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_Monat { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_Tag { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_ERFDAT { get; set; }
    public string ZPZ_ERFUSER { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_MUTDAT { get; set; }
    public string ZPZ_MUTUSER { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you say your code is correct, then there can be no explanation for this behavior that is consistent with our current understanding of physical law. I suggest you publish. I'll call Stockholm and tell them to chill the champagne.

Comment: Probably `PRAESENZZEIT` doesn't have a public property named exactly "Stunden"

Comment: I thought my sql query code was correct in the test, only the output code shows 0.

Comment: Dump the querry just before executing it. Perhaps they are not the same.

Comment: ToList() your querry result in tempo variable  and use a break point see what is Inside. normal debug thing .

Comment: Unfortunately I do not find a solution ..

Comment: Different dates perhaps?

Comment: Put a break point and watch your `query` in VS. Copy paste it in you Management Studio and see the output against your dB

Comment: No, I doubt that some conversion is necessary..

Comment: Query is good, the exposure is just zero..

Comment: Can you show the definition of class `PRAESENZZEIT`?

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks, I put the code in the comment below

Comment: You should edit the question and add that, not add an answer. But, there is no "Stunden" property so `db.Query<>` cannot deserialize that item from the result set.

Comment: I can not find the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your system I can only make an educated guess, but you probably want to change your query from this:

`SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS Stunden`

to this:

`SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS ZPZ_Std100`

This is because class `PRAESENZZEIT` has a property named `ZPZ_Std100` but not one named "Stunden".

I expect `db.Query<PRAESENZZEIT>` will do reflection to map the result set to property names so you need your column names to match your property names.